# Select split rows in Excel and have them print on the same page

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

I'd like to select several rows in Excel from one sheet, that may not be next to each other and when they are printed using the "Print Selection Only" option, show up on the same page, instead of one row per page.

Is this possible? One way that I have done it in the past is just make a duplicate sheet and delete the unwanted rows. This adds a bunch of what i feel are unnecessary steps though.

Comment: What you have done in past is the easier way...

Comment: … or just use the actual file and hide the rows you don’t want.